# ¿Cómo obtener la palabra más grande dentro de un String que no repite caracteres?

Tags: java

Busco encontrar un método donde regrese el tamaño de la palabra más grande que no repite caracteres. Por ejemplo en `ahfdkjhfjdhs` la palabra mas grande es `ahfdkj` porque luego la `h` se repite. Esto también implica símbolos y espacios.

Este es el código que ya pensé pero no funciona:

```
public int getSizeLargestWord(String word) {
    char[] caracter = word.toCharArray();
    int[] contador = new int[caracter.length];
    int contadorRepeticion = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < caracter.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < caracter.length; j++) {
            contador[i]++;
            if (caracter[i] == caracter[j] + 1) {
                contadorRepeticion++;
                if (contadorRepeticion > 2) {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    int valor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < contador.length; i++) {
        if (contador[i] > valor) {
            valor = contador[i];
        }
    }

    return valor;
}
```

Comment: por qué dices que no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que símbolos y espacios forman también parte de caracteres de una palabra (lo cual no queda claro de tu planteamiento), vamos a separar el problema por partes.

1. Determinar si una palabra contiene caracteres únicos.
2. Determinar la palabra más grande formada por letras únicas en un string.
3. Hallar la longitud de la palabra más grande formada por letras únicas.

Para el primer problema, podemos crear un método que reciba un `string` con una palabra y devuelva `true` si no tiene letras repetidas o `false` si tiene letras repetidas. Para ello, podemos recibir el `string`, obtener todos los caracteres que lo forman y eliminar los repetidos. Si la longitud del `string` original coincide con la longitud del `array` de caracteres después de eliminar los repetidos, entonces la palabra está formada por letras únicas:

```
public static boolean hasUniqueCharacters(String input) {
    return input.chars().distinct().count() == input.length();
}
```

Para hallar la cadena más grande que no repite letras, vamos a empezar a recorrer todas las posibles palabras del arreglo, preguntar si tiene letras únicas y si es la más grande hasta el momento. Finalmente, devolvemos la palabra más grande que encontremos:

```
 public static String getLargestWordWithUniqueCharacters(String input) {
        String max = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= input.length(); j++) {
                String word = input.substring( i, j );
                if (hasUniqueCharacters( word ) && word.length() > max.length()) {
                    max = word;
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

El tercer paso se vuelve trivial si ya tenemos la palabra, ya que solo se requiere llamar al método `.length()`:

```
public static int getSizeLargestWordWithUniqueCharacters(String string) {
    return getLargestWordWithUniqueCharacters( string ).length();
}
```

El programa completo se vería como sigue. Puedes ejecutarlo [online acá](https://jdoodle.com/ia/qKX):

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean hasUniqueCharacters(String input) {
        return input.chars().distinct().count() == input.length();
    }

    public static String getLargestWordWithUniqueCharacters(String input) {
        String max = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= input.length(); j++) {
                String word = input.substring( i, j );
                if (hasUniqueCharacters( word ) && word.length() > max.length()) {
                    max = word;
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static int getSizeLargestWordWithUniqueCharacters(String string) {
        return getLargestWordWithUniqueCharacters( string ).length();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println( getLargestWordWithUniqueCharacters( "ahfdkjhfjdhs" ) );
        System.out.println( getSizeLargestWordWithUniqueCharacters( "ahfdkjhfjdhs" ) );
    }
}
```